# SpUsageSiteSearchResults page reports not loading

Tags: reports

In my SpUsageSiteSearchResults.aspx page from the "Site Collection Usage Summary" section, the search results are displaying very well except the 2 reports "Queries with Zero Results" and "Most Clicked Best Bets", both these reports show 
*"No data is available for this report. Usage analysis might have been enabled only recently, or there might have been insufficient usage to result in any values for the report."*
Earlier all these reports used to work very well, and all of a sudden, they have stopped working. I checked for crawler issues, and other possibilities like verified with the "Usage Analysis Processing" from the central admin, but all looks good. Please help. Its been 2 weeks now without this part of reports

regards,
Yakhub